# Deleting multiple files

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, file

I'm kinda stuck here, any help appreciated:

So I have a table with themes, and then sub-themes. Each theme has many sub-themes, and I want to be able to destroy a theme and all sub-themes goes along.

I did this with this controller:

```php
public function destroy()
{
     $comtheme = Theme::findOrFail(request('idDelTCom'));
     $comtheme->delete();
     $comfiles = Subtheme::where('comtheme_id', '=', request('idDelTCom'));
     $comfiles->delete();

     return back();
}
```

Which is working. My problem is the following:

Each Sub-theme has files associated. When I delete a single sub-theme, I can delete the file using:

```php
unlink(storage_path('app/public/com/checklists/'.$file));
```

I've tried doing the same, and it won't work. I figure the problem is with my query, but I can't wrap around what I have to do here...

If I can't work this out I'll just prevent the deletion of a Theme until all sub-themes are deleted, but it would be better to just delete all.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you explain further why exactly you cannot use that `unlink` call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I know I might not have asked the question the right way, so thanks for the  help anyway!

The problem was I was trying to delete several files, and my unlink code wasn't expecting a colletion or a builder obviously. I got it working like this:

```
public function destroy()
    {

        $comfiles= Comfile::where('comtheme_id', '=', request('idDelTCom'))->get();

        foreach($comfiles as $comfile){
            $file = $comfile->file_name;

            unlink(storage_path('app/public/com/checklists/'.$file));
        }

        $comfileDel = Comfile::where('comtheme_id', '=', request('idDelTCom'));

        $comfileDel->delete();

        $comtheme= Comtheme::findOrFail(request('idDelTCom'));

        $comtheme->delete();

        return back();

    }
```

So I get a collection of the data I want to delete, run a foreach loop to delete each file in there. Then I run a builder of the same data to delete it, and off we go.

Answer (score 0):

Use a on observer on your Theme model.  There are many ways to implement this but I prefer to declare it in the model class itself, so in the class for the Theme model put this:

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    static::observe(ThemeObserver::class);
}
```

Of course there would be a use statement pointing to your `ThemeObserver` class up top, place the class where ever you like in the project, with your model or a dedicated observer directory.

In the `ThemeObserver` class you'll want an event for `deleting` like this:

```
public function deleting(Theme $theme)
{
    // delete subthemes here
}
```

You can set up a similar observer for your subthemes where you delete the files associated with them or just do it here.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#observers